# Cannot launch PolicyCenter server from Guidewire Studio on macos m1

Tags: guidewire

I cannot launch policy center 10.2.2 server from the Guidewiere Studio on macos m1. I'm always have an error about missing file `/Users/xxx/yyy/gw/pc/modules/configuration/build/idea/webapp/WEB-INF/jetty.xml`. What I see the sub directory webapp is not created.
It's working fine on windows and linux but not on macos.
Any help? The only idea I've is it's somehow linked to the existing idea ultimate I'd installed but IDEA_HOME points to 2021.1 or java version. These're the only differences between my computers

Answer (score 6):

Usually manually copying `configuration/deploy/WEB-INF` to `configuration/build/idea/webapp` fixes the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I've definitely seen this error on Macs with multiple customers.  As far as I know that error is a red herring and doesn't lead to the root cause.  Unfortunately I run on a Windows machine so I haven't had to solve it directly.

One reference I see is to make sure you aren't installing/cloning onto an earlier copy of Studio as that can cause issues.  Anecdotally I've seen comments that reference the JVM being used on Macs as impacting this error but I don't have any concrete recommendations beyond what's shown in the Platform Support Matrix for self-managed customers, but I've specifically seen comments that Azul may work better on Mac.